# I have a batch file which retries output from Storage and Switch devices

Tags: batch-file

```
@ECHO ON
cd C:\Users\gxgopikr\Desktop\Scripts
#pause
plink.exe -ssh admin@10.0.0.34 -pw $h00tm3n0w "show version" >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt
echo. >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt
echo ############################################################ >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt
echo. >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt

plink.exe -ssh admin@10.0.0.34 -pw $h00tm3n0w "show int brief" >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt
echo. >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt
echo ############################################################ >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt
echo. >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt

plink.exe -ssh admin@10.0.0.34 -pw $h00tm3n0w "show environment" >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt
echo. >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt
echo ############################################################ >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt
echo. >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt

plink.exe -ssh admin@10.0.0.34 -pw $h00tm3n0w "show logging log" >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt
echo. >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt
echo ############################################################ >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt
echo. >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt

echo. >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt
echo. >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt
echo. >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt


findstr /i "down error warning" FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt > nul

if errorlevel 1 goto NOD
if errorlevel 0 goto DOWN



:DOWN
{
{

find /i "down" FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt > nul

if errorlevel 1 goto ERROR
if errorlevel 0 goto ONE-DOWN


:ONE-DOWN
{
echo ################################################################## >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt
echo. >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt
echo **********Few Interfaces are Down!********** >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt
echo. >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt
echo ################################################################## >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt

goto ERROR

}


}

:ERROR
{

find /i "error" FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt > nul


if errorlevel 1 goto WARNING
if errorlevel 0 goto ONE-ERROR


:ONE-ERROR
{
echo ################################################################## >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt
echo. >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt
echo **********There are errors!********** >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt
echo. >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt
echo ################################################################## >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt

goto WARNING

}


}

:WARNING

{

find /i "warning" FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt > nul

if errorlevel 1 goto END
if errorlevel 0 goto ONE-WARNING

:ONE-WARNING
{
echo ################################################################## >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt
echo. >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt
echo **********There are warnings!********** >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt
echo. >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt
echo ################################################################## >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt

goto END

}

}

}

{
:NOD
echo ################################################################## >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt
echo. >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt
echo ***********No Failures!************* >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt
echo. >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt
echo ################################################################## >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt

goto END

}

:END
```

It's perfectly running that my file is calling particular storage array and switch device and executing the command which i have mentioned in the code and saves the output in the text file which i have mentioned in the code, her problem is the output file is not giving in proper way. I need the output with separate lines after command executes and it has to come line by line with neat format.

Please do some modifications on my code and send me the correct code which has to give neat output alignments.

Comment: What are the `{` and `}` characters for?

Comment: those characters are for loop, if any errors or warnings are there in output file it will check internally and will throw the sentence if any errors or warnings.

Comment: I cannot follow; anyway, `{` and `}` do not have any particular meaning to the command processor `cmd`...

Answer (score -1):

Well, I'm having hard time understanding

> the output file is not giving in proper way. I need the output with separate lines after command executes and it has to come line by line with neat format.

But let me guess:

1. You're executing commands on a remote system via SSH.
2. You're saving their output (transferred back to your system by the SSH client) to text files, and they appear to have no separate lines.

Looks like your problem is that your remote system is some sort of Unix-like OS, which uses sole `LF` ASCII character (code 0x0a) as its line separator while Windows uses the sequence `CR`+`LF` (codes 0x0d, 0x0a) for the same purpose.
So the text generated by programs run on the remote system has single `LF`s between the lines of text, and when this text is saved to a text file
which you then open by some dumb text editor (such as Notepad), that text
appears to be a big single line (maybe with funny characters embedded into
where line breaks are supposed to be).

If my guess is correct, there are two ways to solve the problem:

- Filter the output of the command you execute right there on the remote
  system.

  Basically that amounts to changing the command

  ```
  show environment
  ```

  to *something* like

  ```
  show environment | unix2dos
  ```

  Unfortunately, if you're dealing with some sort of embedded system
  (and it appears you do), you don't really get a normal shell in your
  SSH session but rather is talking directly to a specific program
  (which parses those "show ..." commands);
  and it appears that's precisely your case.
- Convert the text on the client side.

  I'm afraid doing this in plain batch language of `cmd.exe` is
  impossible.

  You should either get some external program which would do the conversion (such as [this one](http://dos2unix.sourceforge.net/)) and then
  use something like

  ```
  plink.exe -ssh ... "show logging log" | unix2dos >>FILE
  ```

  or rewrite the whole thing in a more powerful programming language
  (I'd pick VBScript or JScript via WSH or maybe Powershell—though its
  idea of streaming output of programs encoded as UTF-16 might trip you up).

TL;DR
That's probably a problem with [different EOLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-line), and you need to convert `LF`s
coming from remote to `CR`+`LF` sequences.

Comment: It's a good catch and thanks for your explanation and suggestion, as per you i have modified like below but the output file is blank didn't execute it.                                                                                     plink.exe -ssh admin@.... -pw ... "show logging log" | unix2dos >> FCDCMDS_1A_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt                 Please let me know the above syntax is wrong otherwise pls send the one script by using powershell or VBScript (i think you understand what i have put in my old script means concept) because i don't these scripts. Thanks

Comment: Because i know only basics in batch scripting, please send the script (by using VBScript or powershell) i.e, from windows server it has to login to one of my switch and execute the above commands and saves back to the same path on my windows system with neat output text file. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Sorry i have forgotten one point and the script has to give if any failures, errors, warnings in the output it has to display what it's so that we can understand the exact point instead of searching where the failures or errors on output. Please don' mind as i am troubling you soo  much for new script.

Comment: @CGK, sorry but SO is not about solving your problems for you. Explaining what happens and how to go about it is education; writing scripts for you is support. These are different things. So please try to solve that yourself: that's what you supposedly are paid for at your `$dayjob` after all. ;-)

Comment: Sure Kostix... I understand bu the syntax which you given earlier isn't working it's giving the blank text file, please help me with the syntax...

Comment: Well, but I explained why the approach you took will most probably fail, and it failed as was predicted. So, you have verified the first approach (fix the linefeeds on the server side) is not going to work and are hence left with the second approach: fix them on the client side. Please please don't just ask for help; you're programmer/administrator, you're supposed to *actively* work on understanding the clues and trying things out, not just repeatedly asking for a ready-made solution. Don't give up easily!

Comment: Sure...i'll try it as per your suggestions and thanks for the advise.